# How can I remove the 'index out of range' error for a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, smoothing, index-error

I'm a fair beginner in Python and I do understand what is wrong in this case, `SetVel[i+4]` takes it beyond the range. But I can't get my head around rectifying it. Any help would be amazing. Here's my code:

```
OutSmooth = []
IndexOut = []
IndSmooth = []
length = len(SetVel)
for i in range(2, length-3):
    diffnext = (SetVel[i+4])- (SetVel[i+3])
    diffprev = (SetVel[i+1])-(SetVel[i])
    diff1 = SetVel[i+2]-SetVel[i+1]
    diff2 = SetVel[i+3]-SetVel[i+2]
    if diff1 < 1.5*diffprev or diff2 < 1.5*diffnext:
        IndSmooth.append(SetVel.index(SetVel[i+2]))
    else:
        OutSmooth.append(SetVel[i+2])
```

PS: for those asking about what this actually is: It is my attempt at non-derivative curve smoothing. In my main program I do have a NumPy based derivative curve smoothing mechanism, but I have done this for my understanding and as a backup. Thanks

EDIT:

`break` after the condition worked to remove the error, but the code only runs the block once. Only one index is appended

Comment: Your `range()` goes to `length-3`, so `i+4` will go beyond the length of `SetVel`.

Comment: Yeah I understand the cause of the error, so the solution is limiting it to [i] instead of incremented elements of the set?

Comment: Now the problem is that it only prints one element as the answer because of the break, which is definitely not true

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating using `i` that maxes out just before `length-3`, at `length-4` (which infact is equal to `len(SetVel)-4`.

Following this logic, if `i = len(SetVel)-4` then `SetVel[i+4]` is equal to `SetVel[len(SetVel)-4+4]`, or `SetVel[len(SetVel)]`.

All that is just to show you the cause of the error - you are seeking an index that's the length itself. That won't be good, since the indexes start at 0 and not 1. The highest index possible is -1 from the length.

In other words, replace

```
for i in range(2, length-3):
```

With

```
for i in range(2, length-4):
```

Finally, if you `break` the loop at the end of it, unconditionally, you get only one iteration of it (only one result), so just don't do that

Answer (score 0):

highly regular math expressions may be clearer with indexed results rather than named variables
and Python really likes consuming iterators

once you are used to list comprehensions, `zip()` I think generating a list of diffs may be clearer

```
SetVel = [math.sin(math.pi*(n % 10 - 5)/5) for n in range(20)]

diffs = [[ e1 - e0, e2 - e1, e3 - e2, e4 - e3 ]
         for e0, e1, e2, e3, e4
             in zip(SetVel,
                    SetVel[1:],
                    SetVel[2:],
                    SetVel[3:],
                    SetVel[4:])]

OutSmooth = []
IndSmooth = []
delta = 1.5    # may want to change the constant, do it one place

for i, d in enumerate(diffs):
if d[1] < delta*d[0] or d[2] < delta*d[3]:
        IndSmooth.append(i+2) # a guess at what you really wanted
    else:
        OutSmooth.append(SetVel[i+2])

IndSmooth
Out[64]: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17]

OutSmooth
Out[65]: [0.0, 0.0]
```

a common programming goal is to parameterize, automate, so here the input is the number of diffs you want, the rest is automatic

```
n_diff = 4

diffs = [[g - f for f, g in zip(e, e[1:])]
                for e in zip(*[SetVel[n:]
                               for n in range(n_diff+1)])]
```

Comment: Wow.. that makes a lot of sense! Thanks!

Comment: upvotes are the prefered Stack Exchange feedback even if it doesn't directly answer your question, please remember when you have 15 reputation points